# zsh on M1 Pro Mac taking 20 seconds to load

Tags: mac, terminal, zsh, macbook-pro

I have a M1 Pro Macbook pro and I installed zsh on this machine. However, when I start a terminal session, it takes over 20 seconds to load the session. This is really frustrating and I have not been able to find a solution.

zsh version:

```
❯ zsh --version
zsh 5.8.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin21.0)
```

I have tried iTerm2, Hyper & the native mac terminal. Both takes long time to load.

Below is my .zshrc file:

```
export ZSH="$HOME/.oh-my-zsh"
# Enable Powerlevel10k instant prompt. Should stay close to the top of ~/.zshrc.
# Initialization code that may require console input (password prompts, [y/n]
# confirmations, etc.) must go above this block; everything else may go below.
if [[ -r "${XDG_CACHE_HOME:-$HOME/.cache}/p10k-instant-prompt-${(%):-%n}.zsh" ]]; then
  source "${XDG_CACHE_HOME:-$HOME/.cache}/p10k-instant-prompt-${(%):-%n}.zsh"
fi
typeset -g POWERLEVEL9K_INSTANT_PROMPT=quiet
typeset -g POWERLEVEL9K_INSTANT_PROMPT=off
ZSH_THEME="powerlevel10k/powerlevel10k"
plugins=(git zsh-autosuggestions zsh-syntax-highlighting)
source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion




alias k=kubectl
alias tf=terraform

source ~/powerlevel10k/powerlevel10k.zsh-theme

# To customize prompt, run `p10k configure` or edit ~/.p10k.zsh.
[[ ! -f ~/.p10k.zsh ]] || source ~/.p10k.zsh
#compdef _velero velero



export PATH="${KREW_ROOT:-$HOME/.krew}/bin:$PATH"
```

Any suggestions would be really helpful.

Comment: Why'd you build it for x86?

Comment: I did not build it. I just installed it from official document. Is there any way to build it for arm64?

Comment: Doesn’t macOS include a native (Arm) zsh on the Mac? Try to find that instead of installing your own. If you want a different/custom one, you definitely want a native one. Try using Homebrew to install it.

Comment: it does not include native arm64 binary

Answer (score 1):

Check initialization time of each command/module

> Putting `zmodload zsh/zprof` into the first line of zshrc
> and execute `zprof` at the end of zshrc.

See if something spend a lot of time in the initialization. Remove it and change the way you loading it into a function like this.

```sh
loadnvm() {
    export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
    [ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"
    [ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).